# Temperature probe placement

Tags: fermentation, temperature-probe

I just built a fermentation chamber and bought a brew belt and a cheap thermostat on ebay to try to control the fermentation temperature.

My main concern is, where do I place the probe in order to get a reliable measurement of the wort temperature? I don't trust placing the probe directly into the fermenter, so I thought taping it to one side. Is it fine or there are clever and more reliable solutions?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temp probe is most likely not waterproof, indeed.

Many people place the temp probe on the side of the fermentor, with some insulation around it to try to isolate the fermentor-wall temperature from the ambient environment. You'll get close-enough to the wort temperature.

You can also acquire a "thermowell": a hollow, capped stainless-steel tube which fits the temperature probe inside, which you can place in your wort. The temperature probe ends up being roughly in the middle of the wort/beer. This is the most reliable means of testing the fermentation temperature.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. What about measuring the temperature in the fermentation chamber (it fits just the fermenter) and heating that instead of the fermenter? It is the other option I was thinking of.